# PHP + MSSQL : Could not find stored procedure - but it is there

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, php-mssql

Here is my code on PHP:

```
$stmt = mssql_init('postget', $conn);
mssql_bind($stmt,'@IDPost',$IDPOST,SQLINT4);

if ($result = mssql_execute($stmt)) {
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo $row["Content"];
    }
}
```

I'm recieving the error: Could not find stored procedure 'postget'.

The procedure is there, the connection is ok and the init returns a resource...

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: in the same solution are you also working with live db connection string? sometimes we forgot to change it so please check once. if sp is on both dev and live server then it could be another issue.

Comment: Is your proceedure working properly from sql command editor ?

Comment: Yes, it is working properly... There is only the dev server for now... Ah, there is something else really weird: I tested using .net and it also cannot find the proc. If I put a query, it works. But the proc is not founded....